# Mercurial (?) + SVN interoperation

Tags: svn, mercurial, dvcs

I need some suggestions for the following scenario:

- my Uni group has a huge SVN repository. I'm actually interested in a subdir of the whole thing (e.g. say /trunk/projects/my_project) - dunno if it really matters with SVN
- I'll be responsible for 95% of the commits to this project
- I'd much prefer to use a DVCS. Preferably Mercurial since that's what I'm familiar with, but I'm flexible in case something else fits the workflow better
- There will be potentially many smaller individual subprojects within my_project. I want to be able to work on each one individually

The workflow would be something like following:

- create a new subproject
- hack hack hack (branch etc)
- when a reasonably stable state is achieved, include into the main project and push to SVN
- occasionally, I might need to pull some changes *from* SVN (i.e. by other people) into the main project, or even the subprojects. These will all go into trunk, i.e. no branching on the SVN level

I know about the Mercurial [Wiki page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) for SVN interoperability, and I suspect the Mercurial subrepo features might come in handy, but am still not sure how to organize the whole mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lucero suggests, *hgsubversion* is the tool you're generally looking for. Also, as Lasse indicates in his comment to Lucero's answer, using Mercurial's subrepository feature conflicts with how sub- or external repositories are handled in SVN: Mercurial uses plain files to store information about subrepositories and this information is not interpretated by SVN.

Anyway, based on your question it seems you may not need to use the subrepository feature: you only need it in case you want to track interdependencies between individual subprojects. So, assuming you have independent subprojects, just create a directory in SVN below `/trunk/projects/my_project` for each project and use Mercurial with *hgsubversion* for each individually.

The basic message is that *hgsubversion* allows you to **locally** benefit from all the DVCS features but when publishing your work, you are more or less restricted to the capabilities of SVN. You cannot make use of DVCS workflows concerning **team collaboration** when using a central and linear system like SVN as the collaboration hub.

Perhaps it possible to design a (fragile) team-workflow with SVN which imitates some DVCS aspects, but I guess this results in more work than convincing your co-workers to either use Mercurial too or to simply send you patches.

Comment: Yup, I think that should fit the bill nicely! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) is a perfect fit for you. It lets you pull and push to a SVN repo, but locally you have a HG repo.

Comment: Also, the hgsubversion webpage mentions that "right now, you can only clone repositories that use a more-or-less standard Subversion layout", i.e. /trunk, /branches, /tags etc. Would that present a problem?

Comment: How would you work with Mercurial subrepos for a project contained in Subversion? Wouldn't people talking only to the Subversion repository have problems seeing the content of those subrepos?

Comment: @oggy, HG subrepos are just normal HG repos, which are handled (push/pull and other stuff) by their parent repo. As such I expect `hgsubversion` to work assuming that the subrepo is bound to SVN. Also the assumption is that your SVN repo follows the normal SVN naming scheme (trunk/branches/tags), which is best practice for SVN and therefore usually how it is set up.

Comment: @Lucero, see my bullet #1 for my scenario. This is something I cannot change, unfortunately